# Finding integral of a vector $\int(e^{-t}(ti+4e^{3t}j+k)(dt)$

Tags: calculus, integration

How is the following integral found out.

$\int(e^{-t}(ti+4e^{3t}j+k)(dt)$
I did the distributive property.

$\int e^{-t}t(i)+e^{-t}4e^{3t}j+e^{-t}k$

for i I used the integration by parts and got

$t-e^{-t}-e^{-t}i$

for k I got
$-e^{-t}$

but I am not sure how to find the integral for j vector
$e^{-t}4e^{3t}j$

Comment: $e^{-t}e^{3t}=e^{-t+3t}=e^{2t}$.

Comment: I see I forgot the exponent rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int e^{-t}(ti+4e^{3t}j+k)dt=\int te^{-t}dt~\vec{i}+4\int e^{\color{red}{2t}}dt~\vec{j}+\int e^{-t}dt~\vec{k}$$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks my dear friend. :-)